# Pass multiple objects from same servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to send 2 objects (e.g. User.java object and Travel.java object) from my servlet to my jsp page.

Following is my servlet code:

```
    Travel bookTravel=new Travel();
    User user=new User();

    SearchService searchService=new SearchService();
    bookTravel=searchService.fetchBookingDetail(travelid);
    int driverId=bookTravel.getUserid();
    iService fetchUserService=new LoginService();
    user=fetchUserService.fetchUser(driverId);


    request.setAttribute("user", user);
    request.setAttribute("bookTravel", bookTravel);
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/bookingpage.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

Following is my jsp page code block:

```
<% Travel travel=new Travel();
User user=new User();
travel=(Travel)request.getAttribute("bookTravel");
user=(User)request.getAttribute("user");
%>
Here are your choice of travel details:
<%=user.getAddress() %>
<br />
```

For the above code segment, it is throwing null pointer exception when the control moves from servlet to jsp page. However, when I remove one object from the servlet and pass only a single object(In this case: travel).It is working fine. The session attribute cannot be of much help as I am keeping a single variable irrespective of these two objects.

I need to pass both the objects from the same servlet to the jsp page. Am I doing wrong? Are there more methods to handle this kind of situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your access looks fine.  If `travel` doesn't throw an NPE, I'd guess the problem is in `user`.  As a further guess, `user=fetchUserService.fetchUser(driverId);` in your first block of code probably returns `null`.

Comment: I tried by sending one object at a time to the jsp one by one. I did not see that any method call is returning null value. I am pretty sure that the problem might be in interpreting two objects in the jsp page at a time. :(

Comment: As @markspace said, it should not be a problem to pass two different objects in the way you did. It would probably help if you could indicate at what line the NPE is thrown (pasting the exception stack trace into the question even better).

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment of code that you posted the parameter named 'travelid' is not defined.

```
 bookTravel=searchService.fetchBookingDetail(travelid);
```

That seems to be the reason as to why the object bookTravel is causing issues.
Check in your code if you have declared and initialized the variable.